# which protocols are implemented by jdk socket

Tags: java, communication, network-protocols, tcp

If I understood correctly, we use `java.io/java.nio.*` to implement an application which should be a application layer implementation of ISO 5 layer model(maybe not accurate). I think JDK should implement the lower layer (transportation layer, network layer or even L2, L1), if so, which protocols are based. if no, any introduction please?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have very basic understanding of it so confusing a lot of things.

java.nio etc. when provide application layer (OSI layer 7) or sockets (sockets are little lower than application layer since you can make http, ftp etc. on top of them), they do have all the lower layers implemented too. Without lower layers you cannot actually send a single packet across and hence can't communicate.

Whether a programmer has access to those layers and to which level you can customize is a different story.

Usual standard is sockets api which provides a good deal of choice to specify lower layers (tcp, udp, or raw).

Additionally most high level languages provide application layer implementations such as for HTTP, SMTP etc.

Comment: If i understand your opinion, socket is a abstract high level communication implementation, it's have not exact relationship with each protocol and each layer, we can use socket API /*maybe there is a API xxx.sendUdpDatagram() :-).  but actually i never saw one like this in JDK.:-(. */ to specify a protocol(mostly, we choice transportation layer protocol, such as UDP,TCP etc.) which we would like to use.So that we could always dedicate on our application. Also, different language provide different socket API and most similar to each one.

Comment: You choose tcp or udp while creating a socket in general or often you have a different api for creating a socket of tcp vs udp http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html and then you use buffered input stream reader or writer to read or write on the socket. When we say api, the point is that the functions handle all lower layer work for you and you dont have to worry about adding tcp header, calculating its checksum, do ordering (you merely specify tcp), neither you have to worry about adding ip or ethernet headers. That is automatically managed by the sockets api

Comment: Take a look at Richard Stevens TCP/IP Illustrated vol. 1. Just the first chapter alone will improve a lot of your concepts.

Comment: sorry for your so long time waiting. thanks a lot, there is just TCP/IP illustrated in my office, hope it helps.